# How do I output xml in the console in IE?

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

I am trying to inspect an xml file in the console in IE11. In every other browser, all I have to do is add the line `console.log(myXML);` and it will output the raw xml in the console. However, the same code will output an object representation with all its properties in IE11 and Edge. I just want to see the xml just like it's displayed in all other browsers. How do I accomplish this? And why the heck would IE do it differently than other browsers in the first place?

Comment: Try using string formatting: `console.log('%s',myXML);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `dirxml` method.

Per the official documentation found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265067(v=vs.85).aspx

> **Dirxml:** Logs an XML node object to the console.

```
var parser = new DOMParser(); 
var xml = parser.parseFromString("<books isbn=\"1111\"><book><title>Hello world!</title></book></books>", "application/xml");
console.dirxml(xml);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the XMLSerializer?

```
var myXMLstring = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(myXml)
console.log(myXMLstring)
```

Comment: This works but doesn't display the xml in its entirety. Looks like there's a character limit that can't be exceeded when outputting to the console. `dirxml` seems to work better.